# Stripe Checkout with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe Checkout in my Angular 2 web application. Everything works fine until I try to call the createOrder function after I've received the card token.

The error is: `EXCEPTION: this.createOrder is not a function`

How am I able to call the createOrder function after I've received the token?

```
openCheckout() {
let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_OtZk....xbk6UQB',
  locale: 'no',
  token: function (token: any) {
    this.createOrder(token, this.cart); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
  }
});

handler.open({
  name: 'Test Store',
  description: 'Test Description',
  amount: this.cart.totalAmount,
  currency: 'nok',
  email: 'test@test.no',
  image: '../../assets/images/test.png',
  ['allow-remember-me']: false
});

this.globalListener = this.renderer.listenGlobal('window', 'popstate', () => {
  handler.close();
});
}

createOrder(token, cart) {
this.ordersService.createOrder(token, this.cart).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: change your token function to an arrow function `token: (token: any) => {
    this.createOrder(token, this.cart); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
let that = this;
var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'Publishable key',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: async function (token: any) { 
        console.log(token)  
        //IN HERE try to put function (that.createOrder(token, this.cart);)
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).